# ERROR ITMS-90715: "Minimum OS too low

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, native, onesignal

After i tried to add **onsignal** with xcode followed by the docs,
it works as excepect but when i try to upload the application ,
i faced this issue

```
ERROR ITMS-90715: "Minimum OS too low. The 
Payload/App.app/PlugIns/AppNotification.appex extension requires a version of iOS higher 
than the value specified for the 
MinimumOSVersion key in Info.plist."
```

info.plist [AppNotification.appex] 
    MinimumOSVersion
    iOS 11.0

i tried to set iOS Deployment Target for both app and notification extenstion but no luck,

*thanks in advance*

Comment: Which platform do you have in your Podfile?

Comment: set its value to 10.0 and then check again. Basically you are trying to set max value as min. I think you got my point.

Comment: thanks it works with me, i changed deployment ios of onesignal to 10.2

Answer (score 0):

I think for `os_signpost`

- if you are using OC you need Base SDK of iOS 12
- if Swift you need deployment target of iOS 12

Comment: using react native :-